# Angular $interval.cancel() failing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button on my template side which toggles the value of a scope boolean.

In my controller I have a function "scaleHeader()" that on load is triggered with an interval of 500ms.

I only want the interval execution of the function to happen if my boolean is set to false.

In my controller I have a function that toggles the value of the boolean("$scope.block"), I have my "scaleHeader" function and I have a $watch method set on the $scope.block boolean.

The boolean is initialised in the controller as false so the interval is set. But when I press the button and set $scope.block to true the $interval.cancel() dosnt seem to stop the calls to "scaleHeader()"

Here is my controller:

```
app.controller('listeditorController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$route', '$http', '$location', '$modal', '$cacheFactory', '$interval',
  function ($scope, $routeParams, $route, $http, $location, $modal, $cacheFactory, $interval) {

        $scope.block=false;

        $scope.blockToggle = function(){
          if ($scope.block == false){
            $scope.block = true; 

          } else{
            $scope.block = false;
          }
        }

        $scope.scaleHeader = function(){
          if($scope.block == false){                          
            console.log('scaling');

            var colNumber = document.getElementsByClassName('fixedHeader')[0].getElementsByTagName('TR')[0].getElementsByTagName('TH');

            for (i = 0; i < colNumber.length; i++) { 
              var newColSize = document.getElementById(i).getBoundingClientRect().width;

              document.getElementsByClassName('fixedHeader')[0].getElementsByTagName('TR')[0].getElementsByTagName('TH')[i].style.minWidth = newColSize +"px";

              document.getElementsByClassName('fixedHeader')[0].getElementsByTagName('TR')[1].getElementsByTagName('TD')[i].style.minWidth = newColSize +"px";    
            }
          }
        }

        $scope.$watch('block', function(newValue,  oldValue) {
          console.log('block changed from '+oldValue+' to '+newValue);

          if(newValue == true){

            console.log('trying to cancell'); 
            $interval.cancel($scope.ccc);

          } else{$scope.ccc = $interval( function(){ $scope.scaleHeader(); }, 500);}
        });

}]);
```

Comment: log `ccc` before cancel and see if it is undefined?

Comment: not use `alert` for debug

Comment: I changed "var ccc" -> $scope.ccc and the log it gives is "Promise {$$state: Object, $$intervalId: 2}" but still recalling scaleHeader()

Comment: Looks like I have 2 intervals running at the same time?

Comment: This is failing at two levels:1-interval not being cancelled and 2- even though it keeps calling scaleHeader() after block= true the code still runs through " if($scope.block == false){ ...}    "